# Unable to add/implement DocuSign Drop Down Box using Java?

Tags: java, dropdown, docusignapi

I am trying to implement DocuSign's drop-down feature in my application by using its APIs in Java. I didn't find any class to add DocuSign to the template.

For checkbox, we have this:

```
Checkbox checkbox = new Checkbox();   
checkbox.setDocumentId("1");   
checkbox.setPageNumber("1");   
checkbox.setXPosition("130");   
checkbox.setYPosition("564");   
checkbox.setRequired("true");
```

For radio buttons, I am implementing like this:

```
Radio radioItem1 = new Radio();
radioItem1.setPageNumber("1");  
radioItem1.setXPosition("152");  
radioItem1.setYPosition("500");  
radioItem1.value("Male"); 

Radio radioItem2 = new Radio();  
radioItem2.setPageNumber("1");  
radioItem2.setXPosition("205");  
radioItem2.setYPosition("500");  
radioItem2.value("Female");   

RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup();  
radioGroup.setDocumentId("1");  
radioGroup.addRadiosItem(radioItem1);  
radioGroup.addRadiosItem(radioItem2);
```

But I could not find any class for adding a drop down in my document using code.

I have included the following dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.docusign</groupId>
    <artifactId>docusign-esign-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use List class in JAVA SDK.

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/esign/model/List.java

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a drop-down menu item by using the [ListTabs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/List%20Tab.htm) component.

You can see an example in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816142/populate-dropdown-options-using-c-sharp-code-in-a-docusign-template-before-creat)